# something used up my disk, don't know what

Tags: disk-usage, openstack

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sun Feb 23 10:40:22 UTC 2014

  System load:  0.03               Processes:             147
  Usage of /:   100.0% of 9.84GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 43%                IP address for virbr0: 192.168.122.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for br100:  10.0.0.1

  => / is using 100.0% of 9.84GB

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

  Use Juju to deploy your cloud instances and workloads:
    https://juju.ubuntu.com/#cloud-precise

Last login: Sun Feb 23 10:35:47 2014 from act-portal1.gw.csiro.au
ubuntu@openstack:~$ du -sk * | sort -nr154496   openstack-manuals148300 identity-api
129208  object-api
52232   devstack
34480   volume-api
32724   api-site
7952    compute-api
5344    netconn-api
1120    python-swiftclient
32  sh
ubuntu@openstack:~$ sudo rm -r python-swiftclient/
ubuntu@openstack:~$ du -sk * | sort -nr
154496  openstack-manuals
148300  identity-api
129208  object-api
52232   devstack
34480   volume-api
32724   api-site
7952    compute-api
5344    netconn-api
32  sh
ubuntu@openstack:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       9.9G  9.9G     0 100% /
udev            2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           792M  252K  791M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
cgroup          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb         30G  173M   28G   1% /mnt
ubuntu@openstack:~$ du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h
0   .sudo_as_admin_successful
4.0K    .bash_logout
4.0K    .bashrc
4.0K    .cache
4.0K    .gitconfig
4.0K    .my.cnf
4.0K    .profile
4.0K    .rnd
4.0K    .viminfo
8.0K    .cinderclient
8.0K    .distlib
8.0K    .fop
20K .ssh
28K .novaclient
32K sh
108K    .pip
280K    .bash_history
5.3M    netconn-api
7.8M    compute-api
32M api-site
34M volume-api
52M devstack
107M    .m2
127M    object-api
145M    identity-api
151M    openstack-manuals
659M    total
```

Keep getting

```
fatal: cannot create directory at 'bla-bla': No space left on device
```

restart didn't solve it.

---

user251046's method:

```
root@openstack:~# apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoremove -y
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 

ubuntu@openstack:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up localepurge (0.6.2+nmu2) ...

Creating config file /etc/locale.nopurge with new version
ubuntu@openstack:~$ sudo su
root@openstack:/home/ubuntu# apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoremove -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
root@openstack:/home/ubuntu# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       9.9G  9.8G     0 100% /
root@openstack:~# apt-get install deborphan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
deborphan is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
root@openstack:~# deborphan
root@openstack:~#
```

---

Nothing in tmp

```
root@openstack:/home/ubuntu# cd /tmp
root@openstack:/tmp# ls
fileKeMpuD  fileTTvnyD
root@openstack:/tmp# rm *
root@openstack:/tmp# ls -l
total 0
root@openstack:/tmp# cd
root@openstack:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       9.9G  9.8G     0 100% /
```

---

```
root@openstack:~# exit
exit
ubuntu@openstack:~$ du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h
0   .sudo_as_admin_successful
4.0K    .bash_logout
4.0K    .bashrc
4.0K    .cache
4.0K    .gitconfig
4.0K    .my.cnf
4.0K    .profile
4.0K    .rnd
4.0K    .viminfo
8.0K    .cinderclient
8.0K    .distlib
8.0K    .fop
20K .ssh
28K .novaclient
32K sh
108K    .pip
284K    .bash_history
5.3M    netconn-api
7.8M    compute-api
32M api-site
34M volume-api
52M devstack
107M    .m2
127M    object-api
145M    identity-api
151M    openstack-manuals
659M    total
```

Comment: What is the openstack-manuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoremove -y

Also DebOrphan finds Orphaned packages.In Synaptic select Status in lower left and then select not installed.Then remove all not installed.

After you have enough space to install FSlint use it to free up more space.This excellin tool cleans up more than any other program in linux I know.

Comment: it gives me error, E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: Why dont you do that then?It actually works

Comment: @Miranda Mark as solved and upvote please when finished so I get rid of question ban!

Comment: `apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove` didn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: are you sure?You should do what Ive wrote about the synaptic anyway.Did you do that yet?

Comment: deborphan didn't help

Comment: @Miranda ok but did you try synaptic?